# module compiled against API version

Tags: python

I tried to run [a python project](https://github.com/NathalieFouet/Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation) with Rasa, but unexpectedly I had two errors that puzzled me : some `failed to import` messages because `module compiled against API vesion` and other `Python has stopped working`. It's the first time I'm wocoding with Windows. Did I did something wrong ?

```
(cha_env36) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation>python run_app.py
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2018-11-26 19:35:40.214152: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

what version of `numpy` and `pandas` do you use?
I presume that the origin of the problem lies in the incompatibility of your current `numpy==1.13.0` and `pandas==0.21.0` installations. This worked in my case:

```
$ pip install --upgrade numpy
$ pip install pandas==0.21.0
```